# How to import and use a file in django project folder

Tags: python, django, github

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

I'm trying to import the file "am_model.py" in backend/api/views.py.
The "am_model.py" uses files from the easy_ViTPose folder (it is a github directory).

Relative import does not work as it gives me:
I`mportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

Any ideas how can I import this in views.py?

Comment: If the `am_model.py` and `easy_ViTPose` are logically a part of the `backend` put them in the `backend` folder.

Comment: I moved both into the Backend folder. I'm still getting the error: 
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: You should include the code (as [mre]) and the whole traceback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import the file in Django from a folder without Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211481/how-can-i-import-the-file-in-django-from-a-folder-without-errors)

Comment: Ah, as per Yevhen Kuzmovych's advise, I created a new folder inside Backend, used the sys.path.append() to add paths of the folder in my views.py file and it is working. My only issue with this is that now it is tailored to my system. When other teamate pulls this code, he/she would have to change paths in multiple locations (there are  sys.path.append() uses in the am_model.py code as well). I wonder if there is a general solution / coding practice that solves/avoids such issue.